# Unknown syntax error - more than or equal to

Tags: python, syntax-error

Im making a quiz to help me with my astronomy revision but this error came up even though ive typed the code correctly:

```
What is the diameter of the Earth? 13000
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/reddo/Documents/Python stuff/Astronomy quiz.py", line 19, in <module>
        elif answer1 >= 13001:
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
    >>>
```

Here's how i wrote the code:

```
answer1 = 13000 
answer1 = input ("What is the diameter of the Earth? ")

if answer1 == 13000:
    print("Correct!")

elif answer1 >= 13001:
    print ("Incorrect!")

elif answer1 <= 12999:
    print ("Incorrect!")
```

I don't know if I've gone wrong or if it's just the program itself.

Comment: You are reading the `input` as `str`, so you need to convert it to `int` first and then use the comparison operators in your if-else.

Comment: The error message clearly states that you are trying to compare a string and and an int which will never work. "_this error came up even though ive typed the code correctly_" Never assume the programming language is broken for such a simple task. First rule of programming - it's always your fault.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I guess I just didnt look close enough at the text.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert it from string to integer

```
answer1 = int(input ("What is the diameter of the Earth? "))
```

Answer (score 1):

answer1 is a string, so you can't compare that with an integer. Replace your second line with the following to convert it to an integer:

```
answer1 = int(input("What is the diameter of the Earth? "))
```